# How to make my application mount a sparse bundle without showing it in the Finder?

Tags: cocoa, mount, finder

I am creating an application that has a bunch of files saved that are encrypted by using a sparse bundle, just like Time Machine does (my name is just a coincidence). I need to mount the sparse bundle to a mount point (I don't care which one). However, I'm afraid that when it 
gets mounted it shows up on the desktop and in the Finder.

I have two questions:

1. How can I mount a sparse bundle from a Cocoa application?
2. How can I be sure it doesn't show up in the Finder/on the desktop?

---

My SDK is 10.6, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Disk Arbitration framework. Specifically, call the [DADiskMountWithArguments()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/index.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/DADiskMountWithArguments) function, passing the "nobrowse" argument.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows if there is an update to that nowadays and 10.11? (I mean 'nobrowse' option)
Currently it is available only next:

```
/*!
 * @enum       DADiskMountOptions
 * @abstract   Options for DADiskMount().
 * @constant   kDADiskMountOptionWhole Mount the volumes tied to the whole disk object.
 */
```

```
enum
{
    kDADiskMountOptionDefault = 0x00000000,
    kDADiskMountOptionWhole   = 0x00000001
};

typedef UInt32 DADiskMountOptions;
```

cc: @JoshuaNozzi